# Error while installing laravel installation via github

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Problem 1

```
Installation request for laravel/framework v5.2.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.16].
laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those `.ini` files:

```
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10mysqlnd.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10opcache.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10pdo.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20calendar.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20ctype.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20exif.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20fileinfo.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20ftp.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20gettext.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20iconv.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20json.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20mysqli.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20pdo_mysql.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20phar.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20posix.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20readline.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20shmop.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20sockets.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20sysvmsg.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20sysvsem.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20sysvshm.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20tokenizer.ini
 /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20zlib.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile php with mbstring. (out of the scope of this question)

[here's a php7 fork of mbstring](https://github.com/ryantenney/php7/blob/master/ext/mbstring/mbstring.h)